# QWebView display nothing on windows

Tags: qt, qtwebkit

I'm porting a QT application from linux to windows. It's extremely strange process and now I encountered a problem I can't solve. I've compiled code and it runs, but I'm using QWebView and when on linux it displays the page (google maps) correctly on windows I see only a white background. I've read that maybe I need some additional image library, but I don't know the name. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

EDIT: It may be case with images or js - an html input type=text added to a page displays. I've copied to MyAp/imageformats image plugins from QTPATH/plugins/imageplugins and it didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What really helped was setting up QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS environmental variable with value 1 and turning on program using qt, in console I could see that I'm missing OpenSSl libraries. Installation of this libraries solved the problem.

Comment: Having the same problem here. Are you still around? Can you describe in more detail what you did in order to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

this Should help http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/41333-QWebview-not-displaying-jpg-gif-png-images-on-another-machines

and also this http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/deployment-plugins.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem on Windows/MinGW app. I bundled 2 dlls with the installation, libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll and QWebView was able to make https:// requests afterwards.

I copied these DLLs from TortoiseSVN installation which happened to be installed on my computer.